# What alternative to a nested =if() function can I use to return a static value based on another static value?

Tags: excel, if-statement, automation, lookup, nested-if

I hope I phrased that correctly.

I can use a massive (probably with 30-40 different conditions) nested =if() to cover the situation in question, and it would look something like this:

`=if(A2="01501-01","I77",if(A2="06823-04","I323",if(A2="1021-591","I3","")))`

etc etc etc. Which says if the value in A2 is equal to 01501-01, return I77. If 06823-04, return I323. But we have a large number of possibilities here. That being said, 01501-01 will ALWAYS need to be matched with I77, and so on. For the situation itself:

[image]

Column C we will be pasting values from another spreadsheet, and need column D to auto-populate with the proper I number. 95% of the values being pasted in column see will be repeats of previous entries, so they should be tied to a value in column D. For the new Customer IDs, we will want to just put "1" so that when we import this file to our database, the database will auto-assign to a group. I hope this all made sense.

Comment: Us a reference table and `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Do you know of a link on how to use that combo? I've never used vlookup

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: If you have an Office 365 subscription, you may want to use XLookup, rather than VLookup. It's a lot easier to understand. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

Comment: There are also infinite number of YouTube videos about vlookup/xlookup as well if you prefer. They will also explain you how to add 1 in your case (when the reference value cannot be found in your reference list and returns #N/A)

Comment: Thanks. So for xlookup, the lookup value would be the Customer ID and the return value would be the Customer Group?  Can I use the table that already exists or do I need a different "reference table" in another tab or something? So in the blank cell in Customer Group I can enter ```=xlookup(C:C, D:D)```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood but if your database will proceed to assign new groups for those “1” cases you may want to do this matching inside the database or you need to make sure to “always” get the latest reference table from it.

Comment: Your “different” reference table has a column with unique/distinct customer ID and another column with the matching group. Please check the links and related videos.